# How to include a total count of items when doing pagination with skip() and take() in Webflux?

Tags: java, pagination, spring-webflux, project-reactor, flux

I am trying to implement a pagination in Webflux. Let's say `CustomersService.getCustomers()` is returning a `Flux<Customer>`.

```java
public Mono<CustomersResponse> getCustomers(Integer page, Integer pageSize, String filter) {
  return customersService.getCustomers()
    .filter(customer -> someFilterFunction(filter))
    .skip(page * pagesSize)
    .take(pageSize)
    .collectList()
    .map(customers -> new CustomersResponse()
      .items(customers)
      .totalCount(customers.size()));
}
```

Implementing it in this way using `customers.size()`, I get the count of the pageSize. However what I would want is the count of elements available, after applying the filter.

I think this could be solved by doing some list based operations, but I would prefer to have it on the stream level.

```java
public Mono<CustomersResponse> getCustomers(Integer page, Integer pageSize, String filter) {
  return customersService.getCustomers()
    .filter(customer -> someFilterFunction(filter))
    .collectList()
    .map(customers -> new CustomersResponse()
      .items(paginate(customers))
      .totalCount(customers.size()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is not mentioned, I assume `getCustomers` is returning a Flux. In this case, what you can do is to call `collectList()` before doing anything else. This will give you a `Mono<List<Customer>>` then (without blocking) you can process this list of customers using Mono's `map()`. Here, you can finally do the pagination using the stream API, and create the Response object:

```
public Mono<CustomersResponse> getCustomers(Integer page, Integer pageSize, String filter) {
    return getCustomerIds()
            .filter(customer -> someFilterFunction(filter))
            .collectList()
            .map(allCustomers -> {
                List<Long> currentPage = allCustomers.stream()
                        .skip(page * pageSize)
                        .limit(pageSize)
                        .toList();
                return new CustomersResponse()
                        .totalCount(allCustomers.size())
                        .items(currentPage);
            });
}

@Test
void getCustomersTest() {
    CustomersResponse resp = getCustomers(3, 5, "").block();

    assertThat(resp.items()).containsExactly(15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L);
    assertThat(resp.totalCount()).isEqualTo(30);
}

@Data
@Accessors(fluent = true, chain = true)
static class CustomersResponse {
    List<Long> items;
    int totalCount;
}

public Flux<Long> getCustomerIds() {
    List<Long> ids = LongStream.range(0, 30).boxed().toList();
    return Flux.fromIterable(ids);
}
private boolean someFilterFunction(String filter) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Trandafir-emanuel. I am afraid this is explicitly not what I am looking for (this is what I hinted at with the example of `list based operations` given at the bottom of the question). I am looking for something where it's all done on the stream level, without aggregating on lists in the beginning....

Comment: I assume you need `totalCount` to be the total size of the flux, right? like the total number of customers. If this is the case I am now sure that you can do it in a single call.

Comment: what is `customersService.getCustomers()` doing? a REST call? a Jpa query? Maybe a better solution would be to add the pagination there and avoid retrieving all the data

Comment: It's an api call that I cannot influence unfortunately. And yes, `totalCount` should reflect the number of items that are available in total after doing the filter (such that a frontend can calculate the number of pages it could display)

Comment: I see, I'll add another answer with an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can retrieve the customers, apply the filter and keep them as a flux (a flux is a publisher). Then, you can subscribe to this flux twice, first for retrieving the items on the current page and the 2nd time for retrieving the total count. After that, you can mix the two Mono objects to create the final response:

```
public Mono<CustomersResponse> getCustomers(Integer page, Integer pageSize, String filter) {
    Flux<Long> customerIds = getCustomerIds().filter(customer -> someFilterFunction(filter));
    Mono<List<Long>> items = customerIds
            .skip(page * pageSize)
            .take(pageSize)
            .collectList();
    Mono<Integer> count = customerIds
            .count()
            .map(Long::intValue);
    return Mono.zip(items, count)
            .map(pair -> new CustomersResponse()
                    .items(pair.getT1())
                    .totalCount(pair.getT2())
            );
}

@Test
void getCustomersTest() {
    CustomersResponse resp = getCustomers(3, 5, "").block();

    assertThat(resp.items()).containsExactly(15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L);
    assertThat(resp.totalCount()).isEqualTo(30);
}
```

Though, I belive you still have to wait for the whole flux to finish in order to get the size, so I believe there will be no performance difference between the two approaches :)

Comment: Ah interesting, I think this goes in the direction I was looking! I guess there's no way to do that all in one stream to have less declarations here. The other answer you gave involves likely less mental overhead to read than this one though.